# Angular pass a parameter from service to mvc controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to Angular and MVC.I am trying to pass a parameter from my view to the mvc controller. After I delete the record do I need to refresh the view to see the changes.
Thank you in advance for your help.

```
myApp.service("deleteService", function ($rootScope, $http)
{
    this.removeRow = function (recId) {

        $http.delete("CurrentSettingsController.cs/DeleteRecord", { params: { recordId: recId } })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            window.location.reload();
        })
        .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
        });
    }
});

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'companiesService', 'allCurrentSettingsService','deleteService',
  function ($scope, companiesService, allCurrentSettingsService, deleteService) {
      $scope.currentSettings = '';
      companiesService.getList().then(function (value) {
          $scope.currentSettings = value;

      }),
      $scope.allSettings = '';
      allCurrentSettingsService.getList().then(function (value) {
          $scope.allSettings = value;

      }),
       $scope.deleteRecordFromDB = function (recId) {
           deleteService.removeRow(recId);
       };
  }
]);

[HttpPost]
public static void DeleteRecord(int settingID)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("DeleteCurrentRecord", conn))
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.Add("@SettingId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = settingID;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                command.Parameters.Clear();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally you wouldn't do `window.location.reload();` and would just remove the entity from your data model once you get server confirmation

Comment: First, `success` and `error` are deprecated. Use `then` and `catch` instead. Secondly, it is bad practice to use `window`. Angular will reload everything you need. All you need to do is change the data (variables on `$scope`) and the view will be updated automatically.

Comment: Just a heads up, Angular uses two way binding. This means, any change in either the model or the view, is reflected on the other end.

Comment: Thank you .Can you please explain with an example

Answer (score 0):

You can return $http.delete from service, so the promise will be returned. And you can add success callback to controller and refresh view in it:

```
myApp.service("deleteService", function ($rootScope, $http)
{
    this.removeRow = function (recId) {

        return $http.delete("CurrentSettingsController.cs/DeleteRecord", { params: { recordId: recId } });
    }
});

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'companiesService', 'allCurrentSettingsService','deleteService',
  function ($scope, companiesService, allCurrentSettingsService, deleteService) {
      $scope.currentSettings = '';
      companiesService.getList().then(function (value) {
          $scope.currentSettings = value;

      }),
      $scope.allSettings = '';
      allCurrentSettingsService.getList().then(function (value) {
          $scope.allSettings = value;

      }),
       $scope.deleteRecordFromDB = function (recId) {
           deleteService.removeRow(recId).then(
               function(success) {
                   //do refresh here
               },
               function(error) {
                   //error callback
               }
           );
       };
  }
]);
```

Comment: will still reload the page

Comment: Thank you. How can I get the value from the MVC controller and pass it to my "DeleteRecord" method

Comment: Thanks charlietfl, i modified the answer

Comment: If You return some data then you can access it here `function(success) {` in `success`

Comment: Thank you . I am getting the following error: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at Scope.$scope.deleteRecordFromDB (Index:127)

Comment: Did you add the `return` to the `this.removeRow`?